# How can i calculate the balance in excel's powerpivot?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, datamodel

I'm doing this in powerpivot Excel 2013

So i have a table what looks a little like this:

```
name    debit/credit  amount    Date
Jane    C             €10,00    01-01-2013 01:00
Jane    C             €10,20    01-01-2013 06:20
Jane    D             €12,30    03-01-2013 14:13
ETC
```

The table is sorted by date
I want to create an extra column in my data model so the table looks like this:

```
name    debit/credit  amount    Date                Balance
Jane    C             €10,00    01-01-2013 01:00    €10,00
Jane    C             €10,20    01-01-2013 06:20    €20,20
Jane    D             €12,30    03-01-2013 14:13    €7,90
ETC
```

Any advice how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DAX CALCULATE for this.

To simplify it a bit I first added a column:

```
=if([debit/credit]="C",[amount],-[amount])
```

Then I did balance with this:

```
Balance = CALCULATE(sum([adjAmount]),FILTER('Table1',[date]<=EARLIER([date])))
```

It is possible to do it with a single formula but it is more complicated than my sluggish brain can handle now.

UPDATE
Sorry, I missed out on the condition for handling multiple names.

```
Balance =CALCULATE(sum([adjAmount]),FILTER('Table1',AND([date]<=EARLIER([date]),[name]=EARLIER([name]))))
```

[image]

Comment: I Tried it with 10.000 rows and excel stopped with a memory error. Tried it again on my personal laptop and it worked. Isn't there a way where it is more recourse friendly?

Comment: What do you mean recourse friendly? PowerPivot performance depends on memory and also whether you have 32 bit or 64 bit Excel.

Comment: on my 64bit laptop it used 4GB extra RAM for this calculation. this is to much voor the workstation at my work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two `SUMIF` functions, one to sum the credit and one to sum the debit, then subtract the debit from the credit. Use one absolute reference and one relative so that when it is copied down the column the absolute reference remains the same. Enter this into `E2` and drag down:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:B2,"C",$C$2:C2)-SUMIF($B$2:B2,"D",$C$2:C2)
```

Comment: There is no SUMIF for powerpivot datamodel in Excel 2013

Comment: I want to create it in the datamodel